# How to use @media with @supports

Tags: html, css, firefox

After months of searching, I finally found a hack for Firefox, as follows:

```
@supports(max-width: 768px) 
and (-moz- 
appearance:meterbar)
{.parallax-window 
{background-image: 
url("http://4309.co.uk/wp-  
content/uploads/2020/ 
01/Screenshot_2020012
5_205147.jpg") !important; 
background-repeat: repeat; 
}}
```

The determining code, `@supports(max-width: 768px) and (-moz-appearance:meterbar)` works fine in mobile (as I wrote it to do), it's just that in desktop there a malfunction.

Part of the mobile view image appears in desktop view, despite it being confined solely to mobile view through '(max-width: 768px)', as shown above.

Most of the page in desktop is black, like a want it, and made so by using element`.parallax-window`; it's just that a small section at the top has the mobile view image. Not sure how that's happening.

I've tried:

```
@supports(min-width: 768px) 
and (-moz- 
appearance:meterbar) 
{.parallax-window 
{background-color: black;}}
```

And

```
@supports(min-width: 768px) 
and (-moz- 
appearance:meterbar) 
{.parallax-window 
{background-color: black;}}

@supports(min-width: 768px) 
and (-moz- 
appearance:meterbar) 
{.parallax-window 
{background-color: black;}}

@supports(min-width: 768px) 
and (-moz- 
appearance:meterbar) {body, 
html {background-color: 
black;}}
```

All to no avail.

Html

```
<div id="content" 
class="main-container">
<section class="content- 
area  pt0 ">
<div id="main" class="" 
role="main">
<div 
id="shapely_home_parallax- 
2" class="widget 
shapely_home_parallax">      
<section class="cover 
fullscreen image-bg">
<div class="parallax-window 
fullscreen" data- 
parallax="scroll" data- 
image- 
src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-  
content/uploads
/2019/08/download-2.png" 
data-ios-fix="true" data- 
over-scroll-fix="true" 
data-android-fix="true">
<div class="align- 
transform">
<div class="row">
<div class="top-parallax- 
section">
```

[here](https://4309.co.uk)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make the whole background black in desktop view in Firefox.

Comment: Please, edit your code to take advantage of screens wider than 26 characters or whatever you have it set to...

Comment: BTW, desktop browsers support making the browser less than 768px wide. `@supports` is probably not what you want to use here. Maybe nest `@media` under `@supports`? E.g. `@supports(-moz- 
appearance:meterbar) { @media (max-width: 768px) { ... } }`?

Comment: @heretic Monkey good idea, didn't work...